# How to add uiviews vertically (not horizontally) using cgrect with a loop objective c

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have been trying to add uiviews vertically and not horizontally (in other words in a column and not in a row) but I don't think I understand the code properly. I can change and alter things and I understand what is happening but i just can't seem place these uiviews vertically. i have tried hundreds of different things and I'm reading up in cgrect but I still can't find what to do. If someone could just point me in the right direction, it would much appreciated.

```
 - (void) generateChat
    {
    int xcounter = 0;
    int longest = 0;
    _chatListRect.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
    NSArray *commaChat01 = @[@"test 01",@"test 02",@"test 03",@"test 04"];
    for (NSString* str in commaChat01){
        
         CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size;
         CGFloat
          x= 0.0, xt = 0.0,
          y= 0.0, yt = 0.0,
          w= 0.0, wt = 0.0,
          h= 0.0, ht = 0.0;
        
       if (result.width >= 0  && result.width <= 1500){
           x = 15; xt = 7.5;
           y = 10; yt = 7.5;
           w = 75; wt = 65;
           h = 75; ht = 75;
       }
             
        UIView *testview =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((xcounter*(x+w))+x, y, w,h)];
    UIView *labelrect = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yt, xt, wt, ht)];
 
          testview.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
        labelrect.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;
          [testview.layer setCornerRadius:2.0f];
          [testview.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
          [testview.layer setBorderWidth:0.0f];
          UILabel *testlabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:labelrect.bounds];
          testlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
         [testlabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:20]];
          testlabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
          [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
          NSString *line1 = str;
           
           testlabel.text = line1;
           [labelrect addSubview:testlabel];
           [testview addSubview:labelrect];
           [_chatListRect addSubview:testview];
           xcounter = xcounter+1;
}
    longest =xcounter;
  xcounter =0;
    if (longest < xcounter){longest = xcounter;}

           _chatListRect.contentSize = CGSizeMake(100*longest,500);
                     
}
```

Comment: `CGRectMake((xcounter*(x+w))+x, y, w,h)`, you are modifying only the origin x. That's why you end having view side by side horizontally. Just draw it on a piece on paper with an axis, you'll have better understanding or what mean coordinates...

Comment: May be use `UIStackView` instead?

Comment: @Larme thank you for helping. Yes I've tried modifying the y but I'm having no luck. I've tried putting +y and taking away the +x , but the code is no longer correct doing that. I've tried changing x+w to y+h but didn't work.

Comment: @Cy-4AH I'll also take a look at that. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple notes...

First, the main problem is that you are incrementing `x` instead of `y`, so you get a "horizontal list" instead of a "vertical list."

Second - and this is more clearly related to your other (deleted) question - if you have varying height labels...

Each time through your loop, you want to increment `y` by the Height of the label (or view) plus the **constant** vertical spacing value.

So, if you have 4 labels of different lengths, and word-wrapping ends up with heights of, say:

```
80, 40, 30, 30
```

And you start at `y = 20`, and you want `20-points` of vertical spacing, the `y` value for your frames would be:

```
y = 20;

y += 80 + 20;

y += 40 + 20;

y += 30 + 20;

y += 30 + 20;
```

So, here's a modified version of your code... I simplified it to use labels only, but the same process would apply if you're embedding the labels in "containing" views:

```
_chatListRect.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

NSArray *commaChat01 = @[
    @"test 01 - long enough that this label will almost certainly need to wrap onto multiple lines.",
    @"test 02 - short",
    @"test 03 - longer string",
    @"test 04 - longer, and will probably need to wrap",
    @"test 05 - short",
    @"test 06 - longer, and will probably need to wrap",
    @"test 07 - short",
    @"test 08 - long enough that this label will almost certainly need to wrap onto multiple lines.",
    @"test 09 - short",
    @"test 10 - longer string",
    @"test 11 - longer, and will probably need to wrap",
    @"test 12 - short",
    @"test 13 - short",
    @"test 14 - short",
    @"test 15 - longer, and will probably need to wrap",
    @"test 16 - short",
];

CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size;

// we want the first label 20-points from the top
CGFloat y = 20.0;

// we want 20-points vertical spacing between labels
CGFloat vSpacing = 20.0;

// we want the labels to start 15-points from the left
CGFloat x = 15.0;

// we want the same "padding" (15-points) on the right as the left
//  so max width for the labels is
CGFloat maxWidth = result.width - 30.0;

// to get the width of the widest label
CGFloat widest = 0;

for (NSString* str in commaChat01) {
    
    // create the label
    UILabel *testlabel = [UILabel new];
    
    // set label font properties
    [testlabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:20]];
    testlabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    testlabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor;
    
    // we want the text to wrap if needed
    testlabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    // set label text
    testlabel.text = str;
    
    // calculate label size restricted to maxWidth
    CGSize labelSize = [testlabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

    // set the label frame
    testlabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, labelSize.width, labelSize.height);
    
    // add label to _chatListRect
    [_chatListRect addSubview:testlabel];
    
    // increment y by label Height plus Spacing
    y += testlabel.frame.size.height + vSpacing;
    
    widest = MAX(widest, testlabel.frame.size.width);
}

// content size
//  Width = widest label plus left-indent
//  Height = y (which has been incremented each time through the loop)
_chatListRect.contentSize = CGSizeMake(widest + 15.0, y) ;
```

Hopefully, if you go through that code and examine the comments, that will make sense to you.

However... if you are building a "chat app" you almost ***certainly*** want to use either a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView`. If a chat thread gets to several hundred back-and-forth messages, you really don't want to be adding several hundred subviews and labels.

Comment: @ DonMag Wow Thank you. I was trying to rewrite the last question to make it more clear and thats why I deleted it. But your answer here, is exactly what I needed. I have been racking my brains trying to figure out how to get Y position with variable labels heights. I haven't tried your code yet but it looks like what I need. I'm going to try it now. A really big thank you. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ DonMag  Absolutely amazing. It worked like a charm! I have literally spent weeks on this! Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the difference between bounds and frame? When it comes to positioning a view, they aren’t slightly different — they are worlds apart.

Accordingly, set the center of each view to position them precisely within its superview without restriction or oddity:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622627-center

Otherwise, call the setNeedsDisplay method of their UIView parent.

If not that, execute your subview-related code inside a UIView animateWithDuration:animations: block parameter.